# Is there a Google Chrome-only CSS hack

Tags: css, google-chrome

In Mozilla Firefox `top: 56px` shows properly, but in Google Chrome it doesn't show correctly.

Is there any way to set `top` in Google Chrome?

Comment: No, but maybe you can give some example? In http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: Is this the same as your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812093/is-there-a-google-chrome-only-css-hack)? Or is it meant to be a different question altogether?

Comment: Maybe you forgot about `position: absolut;` ?

Comment: jsfiddle.net..actully i dont know how is it work..

Answer (score 7):

There is hack for **webkit** based browser. Write like this:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 
 div{top:0;} 
}
```

This is a CSS Statements that only apply on webkit-based browsers (Chrome, Safari, etc.)

Comment: what you want show with this link

Comment: Sandeep and sandeep. pure coincidence?

Comment: @BartBurg , Yup it's pure coincidence :D http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=week&search=sandeep