# Chrome specific css setting

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have css setting below

```
.user-content {
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
}
```

and Want to have setting if the browser is not chrome? Is there a way to have this setting if the browser is not Chrome
Kim

Comment: Why would you do that just for chrome?

Comment: Req, or specific problem in chrome whatever the reason, it is very legit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a Google Chrome-only CSS hack?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812093/is-there-a-google-chrome-only-css-hack)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812093/is-there-a-google-chrome-only-css-hack.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Browser detection in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400935/browser-detection-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code which targets all Chrome browsers starting from version 28.

```css
.user-content {
  font-size: 2em;
}
@supports (-webkit-appearance: none) {
  .user-content {
    font-size: 3em;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="user-content">I am 3x larger only in Chrome browser, 2x otherwise</div>
```

Check out the other CSS hacks here: [**Browser specific CSS**](http://browserstrangeness.bitbucket.org/css_hacks.html)

Comment: In my css I have the code below: .appliance-content {
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
}
@supports (-webkit-appearance: none) {
  appliance-content {
    height: 100%;
  }
} and it didn't work

Comment: @kim2014 you're missing the `class selector` - `appliance-content { height: 100%; }` -> `.appliance-content { height: 100%; }` (notice the **dot (.)**).

Comment: Thanks a lot Vucko. It worked now. Is there any way that I can have the setting .appliance-content { height: 100%; } for all browsers but NOT Chrome.

Comment: @kim2014 Check my edit. The second rule is just overwriting for Chrome only.

Comment: Thanks But we need to have the second rule. The reason I am asking this question because I have this setting : .row-height { height : calc(100%} and I only want to have this setting for all browsers but NOT Chrome

Comment: Yes, specify the rule that you want for all browsers first and overwrite in the second for Chrome. Check the snippet in Chrome and other browsers, open Developer tools to check the overwrite.

Answer (score 0):

Use the webkit-transition property of CSS 3, it will allow you to create chrome specific styles rules.

for more info: [What is webkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468154/what-is-webkit-and-how-is-it-related-to-css)

[Using webkit](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)

Comment: Chrome has not been a webkit browser for a couple of years now.